# Есть ли способ, чтобы один абсолютный div не наезжал на другой при изменении размера вьюпорта?

Tags: html, css

На картинке то как хотелось бы

[image: На картинке то как хотелось бы]

```css
.top, .middle, .bottom {
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 position: absolute;
}
.top {
 background: lime;
 top: 0;
}
.middle {
 background: cyan;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(0, -50%)
}
.bottom {
 background: orange;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Layout Test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="top"><h1>Top</h1></div>
 <div class="middle"><h1>Middle</h1></div>
 <div class="bottom"><h1>Bottom</h1></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: для этого в верстке обычно используют `position: static`

Answer (score 0):

Решено! Спасибо флексу

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column;
 justify-content: space-between;
 height: 100vh;
}
.top {
 background: lime;
}
.middle {
 background: cyan;
}
.bottom{
 background: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Layout Test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="top"><h1>Top<br>Some more text</h1></div>
  <div class="middle"><h1>Middle<br>Some more text</h1></div>
  <div class="bottom"><h1>Bottom<br>Some more text</h1></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```